# Where are the instance variables coming from on the email-ext jelly/groovy scripts?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

The templates and examples provided by the email-ext plugin on jenkins reference variables such as `build, root, it`, etc.... Where are these variables coming from and where is the documentation on them? I understand to some extent that `it` is the reference to the plugin instance, but that's about where my understanding ends.

If you need reference to the scripts you can see some examples here:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`build`: [hudson.model.AbstractBuild](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html) - your build instance.

`project` == [build.getParent()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getParent()) - the job instance for your build.

`it`: [`ScriptContentBuildWrapper(build)`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/ScriptContentBuildWrapper.java) (internal ExtEmail class)

`rootUrl` Jenkins URL as set in your Jenkins configuration

`template`: template name

Here is [EmailExt plugin code link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin). What you are looking for is in the method [ScriptContent.createEngine()](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/7a78d44765ad5ba4d3bbd4be1eb6ec03bb0926b0/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/ScriptContent.java).

For reference, here is [Jenkins API link](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/index.html).

Comment: When using a build step "Execute system Groovy script" the variable `rootURL` does not exist. I'm using this helper function:

`def getRootUrl(useAbsoluteUrl=false)`
`{`
`    def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()`
`    return useAbsoluteUrl ? instance.getRootUrl()`
`                          : (instance.servletContext.getContextPath()+"/")`
`}`

Comment: And the class where the is 'build', 'it', 'project' etc names are actually set to refer to their real objects is here - the JellyScriptContent class: https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/7a78d44765ad5ba4d3bbd4be1eb6ec03bb0926b0/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/JellyScriptContent.java